# What is ~~ in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators

I was just messing with random stuff, while I found something interesting..

if I have ~ before a number, for example I have tried

```
~110100100 // result will be  " -110100101 "
~11 // result will be " -12 "
```

is it making it negative and reducing it by 1? I don't have any idea, can anyone pleas explain this??

Comment: ones complement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement

Comment: ah thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The operator `~` returns that result:

```
~N = -(N+1)
```

But this is an effect of inverting the value of all bits of a variable.

Double tilde `~~` is used to convert some types to int, since `~` operator converts the value to a 32-bit int before inverting its bits. Thus:

```
~~'-1' = -1
~~true = 1
~~false = 0
~~5.6 = 5
```

Comment: Oh thanks! i've never seen this used widely before so i got confused

Comment: Nice. Short but to the point!